# Geometric generation principle form constructing the Hilbert Curve

Tags: geometry, continuity, curves, fractals

I have some questions on the generation of the Hilbert's space-filling curve. Any help to clarify doubts **a-e** would be very appreciated.

The Hilbert's space-filling curve is a function $f_h:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]^2$ built following this procedure of 4 steps (e.g. from [here](http://wwwmayr.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/konferenzen/Jass05/courses/2/Valgaerts/Valgaerts_paper.pdf)):

---

(step 1) Assume that $[0,1]$ can be mapped continuously onto $[0,1]^2$.

**(a) Could you clarify step 1? Does it mean that I should take a specific continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$? Why is it an assumption?**

**(b) It is not clear to me why I need to think about a continuous map: is continuity a necessary condition for having a partition as described at step 2?**

**(c) Is it true that if I change the initial continuous map from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$ then I will have a different initial partition at step 2? Does this imply that we can get different Hilbert space-filling curves following these steps?**

---

(step 2) If we partition $[0,1]$ into 4 congruent subintervals, then it should be possible to partition $[0,1]^2$ into 4 congruent subsquares, such that each subinterval is continuously mapped onto one of the subsquares.

---

(step 3) The subintervals and subsquares should be such that: adjacent subintervals correspond to adjacent subsquares with an edge in common (it preserves continuity), and the inclusion relationships are preserved, i.e. if a square corresponds to an interval, then its subsquares corresponds to the subintervals of that interval (the mapping at the $n$-th iteration preserves the mapping at the $n-1$-th iteration).

**(d): Are there several ways to make step (3) happening? Does this imply that we can get different Hilbert space-filling curves?**

---

(step 4) Repeat the argument for each subinterval and subsquare ad infinitum.

---

**(e) At a given step $n$, we don't know yet which is $f_h(t)$ for any $t\in [0,1]$. However, should I think about having already a surjective map from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$ or just a 1-1 association between subintervals and subsquares?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see how you would find the assumption that a space-filling curve exists confusing. After all, the point is to construct a space filling curve in the first place - why would we assume it can be done?

I think of it this way: *If we do assume* that there is a space filling curve $f_h:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$, then it makes sense to suppose that $f_h$ might map the sub-intervals $[0,1/4]$, $[1/4,1/2]$, $[1/2,3/4]$, and $[3/4,1]$ onto sub-squares of $[0,1]^2$. This points us to think in terms of self-similarity and, ultimately, Hilbert's actual construction.

And, yes, there are a number of potential variations in the construction. One well known variant is [Moore's curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_curve).

Comment: I don't think the assumption is assuming that a space filling curve exists; I think it is just assuming that it can be continuously mapped.  The word "onto" is not used as "surjection" but as "codomain."

Comment: @alphacapture From the cited paper: "We assume that I can be mapped continuously onto the unit-square $\Omega$. If we partition I into four congruent subintervals than it should be possible to partition $\Omega$ into four congruent subsquares, such that each subinterval will be mapped continuously onto one of the subsquares. We can repeat this reasoning by again partitioning each subinterval into four congruent subintervals and doing the same for the respective subsquares". The assumption of surjectivity is necessary to carry out the induction. Otherwise, one of the subsquares could be missed.